# Ist "Temperatur aktuell" gutes Deutsch?

Tags: adjective

[image]

Isn't it supposed to say "Aktuelle Temperatur"?

Is it some kind of a way to write titles?

Thanks

Comment: It is a kind of a way to fill labels in dialogs. Note that *Temperatur* and *aktuell* may even be different labels, printed by different parts of the program. Perhaps the thing can display other temperatures too, and then only *aktuell* is being replaced by, say, *erwartet*. The label *Temperatur* is not changed at all. You'll see something like it on many screens in many different languages. It is all about saving screen space.

Answer (score 8):

"gut" or "nicht gut" is more or less a matter of opinion.

It is, however, common practice to use shortened expressions that might not necessarily follow grammar rules for technical labels everywhere. You might find stuff like the following:

- > Temperatur heute
- > Temperatur gestern
- > Temperatur Soll
- > Temperatur Ist
- > Temperatur aktuell
- > aktuelle Temperatur

and many more combinations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Whats wrong with the grammer of "Tempetur ist" and "Aktuelle Temperatur" though?

Comment: Nothing. Just in there for you to see grammar doesn't *need to be* wrong ;)

Comment: @Tomas: Well, "Temperatur Ist" is not any better (or worse) than "Temperatur aktuell". After all, it's not the beginning of a sentence like "[Die] Temperatur ist ...", it's taking the "Ist" from "Ist-Temperatur" (the *actual* temperature, in contrast to "Soll-Temperatur", the expected or desired one, depending on the context) to the end.

Comment: @Tomas: the labels in which such technical information is presented are often limited in size. So people use the shortest possible but still more or less readable form in order not to waste too many pixels. I do that too, when I write programs for small screens (or even for big screens).

Comment: @Tomas: FWIW, you'll see the same or similar in, say, English, Dutch, French, etc. These labels do not pretend or try to be grammatically perfect sentences. They are just a short form of the information being presented. In some languages, a proper sentence would be too long. And, as you can see above, label captions like "Temperatur heute", "Temperatur soll" are far from grammatically correct, but tell the user what he is seeing.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not wrong (I have the impression the other answer doesn't address this).

The word **aktuell** is an adverb there. It is not an adjective (which would need an *-e* at the end).

Comment: Well actually, if you don't try to build *sentences*, grammar rules don't (cannot) really apply. The most basic grammar rule that is violated here is that sentences need a finite verb. Those labels don't even claim to be sentences, though.

Comment: @tofro Dem kann ich leider überhaupt nicht zustimmen. Man braucht nicht Sätze bilden zu wollen, um Fehler zu begehen. Es gibt auch grammatische Regel für Adjektive (*der armer Peter* ist schlicht falsch – auch ohne Verb), Artikel (*die Sprung* ist falsch) und weitere Strukturen.

Comment: @c.p. So is '_satt_' in '_wir hatten Sonne satt_' an adverb as well? How about '_Natur pur_' or '_der neue Finanzminister ist eine Art Schäuble light_'?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, though it sounds a bit scientific (like "aktuell" as subscript after "Temperatur"):

> Temperatur <sub>aktuell</sub>
>   Temperatur <sub>erwartet</sub>

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit? As is, this isn't exactly a high quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

The noun phrase *Temperatur aktuell* is not good and not bad, it's normal German. This way of giving weather information is so frequent that nowadays you can find it in everyday conversations.

Remarks:

> 1  "Temperatur aktuell" [: 23 Grad]"

is a short way to say

> 2  Die Temperatur liegt aktuell bei [23 Grad] *or*
>
> 3  Die Temperatur aktuell ist [23 Grad].

German word order being very flexible you can also say

> 4  Aktuell liegt die Temperatur bei [23 Grad].

In these sentences *aktuell* is an adverb meaning 'jetzt' designating the time to which the information of the sentence is applying. It's a 'Zeitangabe' = time designation.

You can give the same information by a different structure:

> 5  Die aktuelle Temperatur liegt bei [23 Grad] *or*
>
> 6  Die aktuelle Temperatur ist [23 Grad] *or*
>
> 7  Die aktuelle Temperatur beträgt [23 Grad].

Here *aktuelle* is an adjective qualifying the noun 'Temperatur'.

At first glance you might interpret *aktuell* in sentence 1 as a postposed non-declined adjective like in

> 8  Natur pur / Sonne satt / Sport total ...

but they are few (only six or perhaps eight), you find them most often in advertising language and in journalism and they have a quantifying meaning ('nothing but') giving them the function of a determiner.

[Beside that you find postposed adjectives in old language (Hänschen klein, ein Knabe jung und schön ...), in menus in a restaurant (Pizza hausgemacht, Kaffee schwarz mit Zucker), in small ads (zu vermieten: Wohnung, komplett renoviert; verkaufe deutsche Grammatik, wie neu) and in some other cases.]

You find the same structure as in 1 in nominal phrases like

> 9  der Tag heute / der Regen gestern  / die Wohnung unten (im Haus)

The missing article (*die* Temperatur aktuell) can be explained as a shortening routine like in newspaper headlines or in news tickers.